# Where should I put the count in this tim sort algorithm, to accurately compare runtime to other algorithms

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, runtime, timsort

I've written a Timsort sorting algorithm for a computer science class, I would like to be able to compare the runtime to other similar algorithms, such as merge sort for instance. However, I am not sure where I should put the count (ie: count +=1)within the code to have an accurate run time. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
RUN = 32


def insertion_sort(arr, left, right):
    for i in range(left + 1, right + 1):
        temp = arr[i]
        j = i - 1

        while (arr[j] > temp and j >= left):
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j]
            arr[j] = temp
            j -= 1


def merge(arr, left, right, count):
    c = 0
    index = count
    length = len(left) + len(right)

    while left and right:
        if left[0] < right[0]:
            arr[index] = left.pop(0)
            c += 1
            index += 1

        else:
            arr[index] = right.pop(0)
            c += 1
            index += 1

    if len(left) == 0:
        while c < length:
            arr[index] = right.pop(0)
            c += 1
            index += 1

    elif len(right) == 0:
        while c < length:
            arr[index] = left.pop(0)
            c += 1
            index += 1


def tim_sort(arr):
    n = len(arr)

    for i in range(0, n, RUN):
    insertion_sort(arr, i, min((i + (RUN - 1)), (n - 1)))
    size = RUN
    while size < n:

        for left in range(0, n, 2 * size):
            if (left + size > n):
                merge(arr, arr[left:n], [], left)
            else:

                left_sub_arr = arr[left:(left + size)]
                right_sub_arr = arr[(left + size):min((left + 2 * size), n)]
                merge(arr, left_sub_arr, right_sub_arr, left)

        size *= 2

    return arr
```

Comment: If you want to know the runtime of your algorithm, I cannot see why you want to add a count variable. I suggest you to use the library [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html), or use the `datetime.now` at start and the end, and substract the end to the start time.